# How to update a meeting? Error: Argument Not Optional

Tags: vba, outlook

After a recent Outlook update, this code started returning

> "Compile Error:Argument Not Optional"

The line **`Set Travel = Items.Add`** is triggering the error.

```
Public Sub AddTravelTime()
  Dim coll As VBA.Collection
  Dim obj As Object
  Dim Appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
  Dim Travel As Outlook.AppointmentItem
  Dim Items As Outlook.Items
  Dim Before&, After&
  Dim Category$, Subject$  

'1. Block minutes before and after the appointment
  Before = 30
  After = 30  

'3. Assign this category
  Category = "Meeting Cushion Time"  
  Set coll = GetCurrentItems
  If coll.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
  For Each obj In coll
    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.AppointmentItem Then
      Set Appt = obj
      If TypeOf Appt.Parent Is Outlook.AppointmentItem Then
        Set Items = Appt.Parent.Parent.Items
      Else
        Set Items = Appt.Parent.Items
      End If      

'4. Use the main appointment's subject
      Subject = "Meeting Cushion Time"      
      If Before > 0 Then
        Set Travel = Items.Add ' <------ Compile Error
        Travel.Subject = Subject
        Travel.Start = DateAdd("n", -Before, Appt.Start)
        Travel.Duration = Before
        Travel.Categories = Category
        Travel.Save
      End If      
    If After > 0 Then
        Set Travel = Items.Add
        Travel.Subject = Subject
        Travel.Start = Appt.End
        Travel.Duration = After
        Travel.Categories = Category
        Travel.Save
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function GetCurrentItems(Optional IsInspector As Boolean) As VBA.Collection
      Dim coll As VBA.Collection
      Dim Win As Object
      Dim Sel As Outlook.Selection
      Dim obj As Object
      Dim i&  
      Set coll = New VBA.Collection
      Set Win = Application.ActiveWindow  
      If TypeOf Win Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        IsInspector = True
        coll.Add Win.CurrentItem
      Else
        IsInspector = False
        Set Sel = Win.Selection
        If Not Sel Is Nothing Then
          For i = 1 To Sel.Count
            coll.Add Sel(i)
          Next
        End If
      End If
      Set GetCurrentItems = coll
End Function
```

The goal is to add a time buffer before and after each meeting.

Comment: Try `Set Travel = Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)`.

Comment: 'Argument not optional' translates to "I was expecting some more info to tell me what to do but you've left it out" if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details @SpencerBarnes

Comment: Let me give that a try @BigBen and get back to you. Thank you guys for the help, I really appreciate it

Comment: the line code is incomplete `Set Travel = Items.Add`  [Add method (VBA)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/add-method-visual-basic-for-applications#:~:text=%20Add%20method%20%28VBA%29%20%201%20Syntax.%20An,class%20called%20Class1%20containing%20a%20Public...%20More%20)

Answer (score 0):

The `travel` object is defined as an instance of the `AppointmentItem` class:

```
Dim Travel As Outlook.AppointmentItem
```

But in the code, you are trying to set another item type:

```
Set Travel = Items.Add
```

The default item type for a folder will be returned. Of course, it depends on the folder. But I suspect it is not an appointment item in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If "Items.Add" is asking for more arguments, the implication is the items in that collection have more non-optional arguments, so the default items for that folder are not appointment items.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddTravelTime()

    Dim coll As VBA.Collection
    Dim obj As Object
    
    Dim Appt As AppointmentItem
    Dim Travel As AppointmentItem
    
    Dim Items As Items
    
    Dim Before As Long
    Dim After As Long
    
    Dim Subject As String

    ' Block minutes before and after the appointment
    Before = 30
    After = 30

    Set coll = GetCurrentItems
    
    If coll.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
  
    For Each obj In coll
    
        If TypeOf obj Is outlook.AppointmentItem Then
        
            Set Appt = obj
            Debug.Print "Appt.Subject: " & Appt.Subject
            
            'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.defaultitemtype
            'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olitemtype

            If TypeOf Appt.Parent Is outlook.AppointmentItem Then
            
                ' recurring appointment
                Debug.Print "Appt.Parent.Parent: " & Appt.Parent.Parent
                Debug.Print Appt.Parent.Parent.DefaultItemType ' 1 = olAppointmentItem
            
                If Appt.Parent.Parent.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem Then
                    Set Items = Appt.Parent.Parent.Items
                    
                Else
                    Debug.Print Appt.Parent.Parent.DefaultItemType
                    MsgBox "Default item in " & Appt.Parent.Parent & " is not appointment item."
                    Exit Sub
                    
                End If
            
            Else
            
                Debug.Print "Appt.Parent: " & Appt.Parent
                Debug.Print Appt.Parent.DefaultItemType ' 1 = olAppointmentItem
                
                If Appt.Parent.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem Then
                    Set Items = Appt.Parent.Items
                    
                Else
                    Debug.Print Appt.Parent.DefaultItemType
                    MsgBox "Default item in " & Appt.Parent & " is not appointment item."
                    Exit Sub
                    
                End If
                    
            End If
            
            Subject = "Meeting Cushion Time"
            
            If Before > 0 Then
                Set Travel = Items.Add
                Travel.Subject = Subject
                Travel.Start = DateAdd("n", -Before, Appt.Start)
                Travel.Duration = Before
                Travel.Save
            End If
            
            If After > 0 Then
                Set Travel = Items.Add
                Travel.Subject = Subject
                Travel.Start = Appt.End
                Travel.Duration = After
                Travel.Save
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub


Private Function GetCurrentItems(Optional IsInspector As Boolean) As VBA.Collection

    Dim coll As VBA.Collection
    Dim Win As Object
    Dim Sel As Selection
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set coll = New VBA.Collection
    Set Win = ActiveWindow
    
    If TypeOf Win Is outlook.Inspector Then
        IsInspector = True
        coll.Add Win.CurrentItem
        
    Else
        IsInspector = False
        Set Sel = Win.Selection
        If Not Sel Is Nothing Then
            For i = 1 To Sel.Count
                coll.Add Sel(i)
            Next
        End If
        
    End If
    
    Set GetCurrentItems = coll

End Function
```